# How can I run a Unity web game at full screen?

Tags: unity-web-player

How can I run games that plays with the Unity web player at full screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless it has been disabled in the HTML, all Unity web player games have a right-click menu, which includes a "Go Fullscreen" option.

If that menu or that option has been disabled, then the game would have to include the function directly, e.g. via a button which toggles between windowed and fullscreen.